# Accessing content folder from js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to access image which is located in ~\Content\img folder. I'm trying to do that from JavaScript file which is located in ~\Scripts folder. This an MVC application.

U have tried absUrl + "\Content\img" + fileName. But it gives me Controller\Content\img\fileName.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the `@Url.Content` helper:

```
@Url.Content("~/img/fileName.png")
```

In case you use a separate javascript file you can put a `<script>` block in the beginning of the view page:

```
<script>
    var ROOT = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

And then refer to the `ROOT` variable in javascript:

```
var imagePath = ROOT + '/img/fileName.png';
```

Comment: But can I use it inside js file?

Answer (score 1):

Forward slashes...

\Content\img\fileName.jpg

Should be

/Content/img/fileName.jpg